# sma calcualted in talib in reverse order

Tags: python, pandas, ta-lib

i have a panda

```
timestamp_column
2024-01-31 14:23:10    794.65
2024-01-31 14:23:00    794.65
2024-01-31 14:22:50    794.65
2024-01-31 14:22:40    794.65
2024-01-31 14:22:30    794.65
2024-01-31 14:22:20    794.65
Freq: -10S, Name: close, dtype: float64
```

im using the below code -

```
ma_value = talib.SMA(close_df, ma_period)
```

the result im getting is in reverse order, its from old to new, but i want new to old. i dont see any option to do this in talib. please help

```
timestamp_column
2024-01-31 14:23:10       NaN
2024-01-31 14:23:00       NaN
2024-01-31 14:22:50       NaN
2024-01-31 14:22:40       NaN
2024-01-31 14:22:30       NaN
2024-01-31 14:22:20    794.65
Freq: -10S, dtype: float64
```

i want the result to be

```
  2024-01-31 14:23:10       764.65
    2024-01-31 14:23:00       NaN
    2024-01-31 14:22:50       NaN
    2024-01-31 14:22:40       NaN
    2024-01-31 14:22:30       NaN
    2024-01-31 14:22:20       NaN
```

Comment: Have you tried `talib.SMA(close_df[::-1], ma_period)[::-1]`?

Comment: this works as workaround! thanks.